# Binding interface via ToMethod to a method with a parameter

Tags: ninject

I think what I'm looking for is something very simple, yet I am unable to find any examples.
I'd like to use Ninject to create an object by having Ninject call a factory method with a parameter specified and not injected during the actual request to instantiate the object:

Request for an object here:

```
StandardKernel.Get<ISomeInteface>(new Ninject.Parameters.Parameter("dataContext", dataContext, true));
```

And I'd like to map the ISomeInterface to a method that is expecting a value to be passed to it at runtime.

Mapping an interface here:

```
Kernel.Bind<ISomeInterface>().ToMethod(SomeObject.Create(--> `what do I put here?`));
```

Is this possible?  If so, how do I properly map my interface?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ToMethod(ctx => 
    SomeObject.Create(
        (IDataContext)ctx.Parameters.Single(p =>p.Name == "dataContext")
        .GetValue(ctx, null))
```

But you should rethink your design to avoid calling `Get` from anywhere else than your composite root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, the code does not compile.  And yes, I am planning to call the factory method from the composite roots.. there is an inheritance hierarchy for those (since there is a lot of them) and I have a single factory for them all to use

Comment: the compiler is having issues converting between Parameter object and my IDataContext object that Create() function takes

Comment: You can also use an NInject Provider. In your case, I think the NInject Provider will not add any benefits except from a point of view of semantic. I mean, with the provider, you pass the instance of the provider to NInject to create objects compared to a factory where you must have a factory instance elsewhere while creating the binding to the factory method. For some, the use of provider have a better meaning than a factory in your case.... I think, I'm not sure ... :) The best would be to ask the gods of Ninject; Ruben and/or Remo about this.